# How to render events on different row in React-big-calender day and week view?

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am using react-big-calendar to render events, and I using month,week,days view. Everything works fine in month view, but if there are multiple events with same time slots then it would render in a single row(ref image below). Is there any way to render the event column-wise? Also, are there any good alternatives to react-big-calendar?

[image: week view]

[image: day view]

[image: month view]

Comment: could you tell us how did you achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the documentation site is out of date, or you'd know about the new `dayLayoutAlgorithm` prop. From the updated documentation (available by cloning the repo and running the 'examples'):

> **dayLayoutAlgorithm**
>
> A day event layout(arrangement) algorithm.
>
> `overlap` allows events to be overlapped.
>
> `no-overlap` resizes events to avoid overlap.
>
> or custom `Function(events, minimumStartDifference, slotMetrics,
> accessors)
>
> type: `custom`
>
> default: `overlap`